CloudFront 403 Error When Accessing Amplify App - Origin Settings and Permissions Issues
I am attempting to set up an AWS CloudFront distribution for my frontend application deployed on AWS Amplify. The application works correctly when accessed directly via the Amplify URL (master.d1k9ckqlhahmal.amplifyapp.com), but when I try to access it through the CloudFront URL (d1tah0atqbuh9k.cloudfront.net), I receive a 403 ERROR:
#amplify
I wanted to achieve path-based routing to different parts of the app under the same CloudFront domain.
